# KnockoutJS model propety not being sent to server

Tags: knockout.js

I have an ASP.NET MVC application using KnockoutJS and jQuery.

My KnockoutJS model looks like this:

```
    var jsonPass = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model.ExitPass, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, jsonSettings));

        var ExitPass = function(exitPass) {
            var self = this;
            self.incidentId = ko.observable(exitPass.IncidentId || 0);
            self.employeeId = ko.observable(exitPass.EmployeeId || 0);
            self.employerId = ko.observable(exitPass.EmployerId || 0);
            self.employerDesc = ko.observable(exitPass.EmployerDesc);
            self.employeeNumber = ko.observable(exitPass.EmployeeNumber);
            self.employeeName = ko.observable(exitPass.EmployeeName);
            self.createdByName = ko.observable(exitPass.CreatedByName);
            self.incidentDate = ko.observable(exitPass.IncidentDate);
            self.incidentCode = ko.observable(exitPass.IncidentCode);
            self.incidentCodeDesc = ko.observable(exitPass.IncidentCodeDesc);
            self.incidentTypeId = ko.observable(exitPass.IncidentTypeId || 0);
            self.incidentType = ko.observable(exitPass.IncidentType);
            self.permitType = ko.observable(exitPass.PermitType);
            self.outHour = ko.observable(exitPass.OutHour);
            self.inHour = ko.observable(exitPass.InHour);
            self.place = ko.observable(exitPass.Place);
            self.subject = ko.observable(exitPass.Subject);
            self.securityStaffId = ko.observable(exitPass.SecurityStaffId || 0);
            self.authorizer = ko.observable(exitPass.Authorizer || 0);
            self.notes = ko.observable(exitPass.Notes);
        };
var App = function (exitPassData) {

                var self = this;

                self.exitPass = new ExitPass(exitPassData);

            };

            var appViewModel = new App(jsonPass);

            ko.applyBindings(appViewModel);
```

When I save to server I using ajax like this:

```
// save method
 $.ajax({

     url: '@Url.Content("~/Incident/UpdateExitPass")/',
     type: 'POST',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: ko.toJSON(appViewModel.exitPass),
     success: function(response) {

     },
     error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

     }
 });
```

The issue I'm having is that some properties are not being sent to the server, for example "`authorizer`" is not sent to server. I have check that using Developer tools (Chrome) and the request payload is:

[image]

> Is "authorizer" a reserved word? Any clue?

I think I found the issue, and is related on the HTML binding element:

```
  <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Authorizer</label>
                        <select id="cboAuthorizer" class="form-control" data-bind="value: exitPass.authorizer">
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

I have like this, and if I remove the `data-bind` element then I can see the property in the Payload.

> Any clue?

Comment: can you try $root.authorizer instead of exit.authorizer in your html?

Comment: [This is potentially](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342285/ko-tojson-seems-to-be-ignoring-fields) a duplicate.  Note the use of the `data-bind` attribute - specifically the ordering of `value` and `options` (you don't include the `options` in your example above, are you using it?).  Also note that `ko.toJSON` doesn't include elements with null values, as mentioned in a comment on the answer.